Simple Question About Sober Spaces
Let $X$ be a sober topological space. Let $U\subset X$ be an open set. Is the set $\{x\in X:U\not\subset X\smallsetminus \overline{\{x\}}\}$ equal to $U$? Here is my attempt so far: We know that $X\smallsetminus \overline{\{x\}}$ is the same as the union of the complements of all closed subsets of $X$ containing $x$. Then to say that $U$ is not in that union is to say that $U$ is an open set containing $x$. But I don't see where sobriety is used at all!

Welcome to the site. I'm not so confident in your reasoning, but notice $U\not\subset X\setminus\overline{{x}}$ if and only if $U\cap\overline{{x}}\neq\emptyset$. What can you say about that? Bear in mind that $U$ is open. You will find that $U={x\in X:U\not\subset X\setminus\overline{{x}}}$ for any open $U$ and any topological space $X$, sobriety not required
